# How can I access inner html text from another aspx page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I access the input type text from another .aspx page?

```
<div id="login">
    Logged in as: <input type="text" id="Label1" />
</div>
```

Comment: you can't unless you are loading these pages in iframe or something like that in same request. Because HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Submit the form, save the value in your server. When you create the new page use the saved value.

Comment: Use Session for such cases. After a successful login, setup your session variables and you can use them throughout the session cycle until its destroyed (Logout)